# What is the difference between Reality-based UTXO ledger and Voting DAG

Tags: tangle

I was reading the paper Tangle 2.0, which explains the recent research advancement in the protocol. I understand the fact that UTXO ledger can have conflicts and these conflicts are resolved by selecting the reality in the branch DAG. However, I am not sure how this reality-based ledger is connected with on-tangle voting, which results in Voting DAG.

My question is, why do we perform the on-tangle voting or why we create the voting-based dag in the first place.

My second question is, do we perform on-tangle voting before reality selection algorithm on the branch DAG?

Thanks